# SAML2 Authentication with .NET Core and Angular 2+

Tags: angular, authentication, .net-core, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to use saml2 for SSO in my Application. Whenever the user comes on a landing page, I want it to redirect to login page and after successful login, it should get redirect to the home page. I'm using .NET Core 2.2 for my back end and Angular 2+ for front end.

As these are two different applications(front end and back end), how do I generate a token on front end and validate with the back end API?. The identity provider is Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a ASP Razor page.
On Successful Authentication at IDP, it calls the service provider (your razor page)
Create token and store in localstorage with the razor page if you validate the IDP request and redirect to your angular domain url.